# Textarea with lines under each row of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I design a textarea with lines under each row of text like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created this for you in jsfiddle, is this what you are looking for?

```
<style>
._ta { 
    background-color:#AADDF2;
    padding:10px;
}
._ta textarea { 
    background: transparent url(http://s24.postimg.org/62v2ipx81/underline.png) repeat; 
    border:none;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FF9900}
</style>


<div class="_ta">
        I like my name because:<br />
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TV47t/1/

Comment: it will need a slight alteration on the css to handle the overflow but its a good, simple working example for you.

Comment: @Er.KT you will need to tweak the `line-height` and the size of the line spacing on the background image, once you type more lines than you can see, the text will move up and will be out of sync with the lines... by getting the correct line-height and image size you will be able to have it looking nice ;-)

Comment: thanks buddy, i think here in ._ta textarea {overflow:auto;} will be better

Comment: One issue here is when you enter text more then 5 lines then at the time of moving up text align breaks,so please help me to fix this

Comment: That was what my last comment suggested. You just need to fiddle with the line height and the size of the background image then it will be ok. I'm away from the office today but could take a look for you tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-image` or `CSS gradients` to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: am thinking the same but in the case of background-image may will get problem of font size

Comment: No. You have to keep a div with background image and under that create textarea.

Comment: but how to manage small later here like "p", now here half part of p goes under the line and half above the line so now how to manage this?

Comment: Set background pattern with lines (resize related) then set `font-family`, `font-size` and `line-height` for text.

Comment: when you make the text area, you have to position the div and textarea accordingly, so that it makes the accommodation for every character in the way as mentioned in the image along with `font-size`, `line-height` and other CSS attributes. - @Er.KT