# How to set a bottom border for every row in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to add a `border-bottom` line for every row within a `<textarea>`, however I am only able to get the very bottom row's `border-bottom` to do this.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```css
.input-borderless {
  width: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(241,250,247);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Describe the project"></textarea>
```

Comment: Add a background-image to it with lines of required height

Comment: I want this to be responsive. Isn't there another way?

Comment: Can you describe more for *responsive* you said?

Comment: If I make it have a background-image, it will size weird with smaller screens. There isn't another way to do this?

Comment: You can use media queries to change the background-size property and have the background image scale as you desire for different viewports. Also, your classname seems very contradictory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea with lines under each row of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071043/textarea-with-lines-under-each-row-of-text)

Answer (score 15):

You can use gradient as the background image to get an effect that looks like underline:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um70ywzo/)

```
textarea
{
  line-height: 4ch;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent calc(4ch - 1px), #E7EFF8 0px);
  background-size: 100% 4ch;
}
```

Comment: I'd take this a step further and use `ch` units which is the height of the 0 character.  Then you can adjust the font-size and everything will still work.

Comment: This is a modern solution and fully css implemented (no repeated background image, etc.) and it should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to use *layers*, make the textarea as top layer, the multiple lines as bottom layer.

I'm using a pseudo element for the bottom layer, since `:before` and `:after` does not work on a `textarea`, so I set it on the container `div` element.

For the bottom lines, I simply use underscores `_`, with `\A` for a line break, you can have as many lines as needed with a number of  `\A`. The height of each line will get updated automatically according to the font size.

**[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ouwuj0g/)**

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:before, .container textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "____________________\A____________________";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: silver;
  line-height: 1.4;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Hello"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and I can't get it to work. I adapted it to my code somewhat. I don't know what I am doing wrong... https://jsfiddle.net/LyadLn5t/#&togetherjs=zFJxkJ1jrI

Comment: I updated the answer with a better approach. The fiddle in your comment is almost empty by the way, maybe you pasted a wrong link.

Answer (score 3):

Last week I found out about `contenteditable`. This morning, this thought suddenly came to me: Using an SVG background in a textarea doesn't scroll without the help of Javascript, but I bet it would scroll just fine with a DIV. Voila!

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 4em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
#paper {
  min-height: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-size: 1px 1em;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1em'%3E%3Crect id='background' height='1em' width='1' y='0' x='0' fill='%23f1faf7'/%3E %3Cline id='underline' y2='1em' x2='0' y1='1em' x1='1' stroke='%23008000' fill='none'/%3E %3C/svg%3E");
  /*for placeholder, see https://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc */
}
```

```html
<textarea id="TA"></textarea>
<div id="wrapper"><div contenteditable="true" id="paper">I am trying to figure out how to add a border-bottom line for every row within a, however I am only able to get the very bottom row's border-bottom to do this.</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything, minus the internal padding.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea.styleme').scroll(function(event) {
    $(this).css({'background-position': '0 -' + $(this).scrollTop() + 'px'})
  })
})
```

```css
textarea.styleme {
  width: 80%;
  border: 0px;
  /*background-color: rgba(241,250,247, .5);
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/350x100');*/
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 20'%3E%3Crect id='background' height='20' width='10' y='0' x='0' fill='%23f1faf7'/%3E %3Cline id='underline' y2='20' x2='0' y1='20' x1='10' stroke='%23008000' fill='none'/%3E %3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 10px 20px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  /*padding: 10px 0;*/
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea spellcheck="false" class="styleme" placeholder="Describe the project" rows="5">Vestibulum vel sem porttitor, suscipit odio sit amet, egestas arcu. Nam varius felis eu ligula pellentesque vestibulum. Pellentesque tempor, nisi sit amet fringilla consequat, ex erat malesuada dui, non dapibus nunc felis laoreet nibh. Maecenas elementum commodo enim quis hendrerit. Ut sit amet malesuada dui. Praesent dolor purus, mollis vel venenatis eget, malesuada sed nulla. Sed at dolor lobortis, malesuada tortor ut, ultrices enim. Nullam posuere dolor massa. Nullam dignissim, dolor at tempus sagittis, massa eros semper quam, a posuere massa massa et neque. Praesent finibus massa eu interdum auctor. Vestibulum id risus massa.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How to underline all text in a <textarea>

Your question says you want *a `border-bottom` line for every row within a `<textarea>`*, so my answer may not exactly meet your needs. I'll post it in case it's useful to you or others.

```css
textarea { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

### [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LyadLn5t/1/)

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: He is not asking for underline for text he is asking line for every row in textarea.

Comment: That's already factored into my answer. Please read the first paragraph. @artuc